# Converting a combobox to int

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to convert a string from a combobox to a usable integer format

my relevant piece of code:

```
Dim intDays As Integer
intDays = Convert.ToInt32(cboDays.Text)
lblDays.Text = intDays
```

After selecting my number for days, the label should change to the value for days selected if it had successfully been converted to an integer but it did not, so I am clearly missing something

Comment: i can n't understand clearly show the selection changed event or show sample

Comment: let me know what you are trying to achieve? what is your expected output

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the combobox SelectedIndexChanged to do this otherwise your code will not get called.
Then your code works.

[image]

Double click there to make the event.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboDays.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim intDays As Integer
    intDays = Convert.ToInt32(cboDays.Text)
    lblDays.Text = intDays
End Sub
```

---

```
If lstRentalType.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
'code ......
Else
'msgbox.....
End If
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this.

I have it within the method along with quiet a lot of code which is why i didn't just copy paste the whole thing because most of it is irrelevant to this situation.
I'll include a link to pastebin containing the entire code
http://pastebin.com/VMXvGHaD

Anyways

Comment: @Ozymandias your if statement is wrong.the code was not working because it never got called. i will add it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your combobox set to DropDownList, then the correct code is:

```
lblDays.Text = CInt(cboDays.SelectedItem.ToString)
```